# CSS: Duplicate Selectors vs. Duplicate Declarations

Tags: css, optimization

Which CSS authoring technique do rendering engines process more efficiently:

1) repeating the same style property/value pair in multiple selectors, or

2) grouping shared style properties in a single selector

Example 1: Duplicate font-size, but less rules

```
p {
font-size: 1em;
color: #000;
}

h1 {
font-size: 1em;
color: #fff;
}
```

or Example 2: More rules but one font-size

```
p, h1 {
font-size: 1em;
}

p {
color: #000;
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This question is opinion based. Personally, I would use the second example if the values must be the same for some reason. If it's just by chance, maybe the first one.

Comment: Typically people define their CSS rules by grouping functionality. So certain portions of the page (nav, content, title) will be grouped. Aside from that, both work and are totally personal preference.

Comment: @mods: Edited to be non-opinion-based; can be taken off hold (IMO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [study by Dave Gregory](http://screwlewse.com/2010/08/different-css-techniques-and-their-performance/) is the best source I've found on this topic. It shows that duplicating property/value pairs is much worse for performance:

[image]

"Long" is what Gregory refers to as the "bloated" format where properties are repeated in multiple selectors.

Comment: I guess nothing has changed in current browsers?

Comment: The one major update to consider is Chrome's switch to the [Blink rendering engine](http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/47054222305/blink-chromes-new-rendering-engine). To my knowledge, nothing has changed yet about the way Blink handles render tree construction or rule sorting.

Answer (score 1):

for performance is better the second option, see this [google advice](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-css), but take care of using declarations in just one place, you could finish with something [like this](http://pastebin.com/Jy9PqFTy), this is the problem with extend in css preprocessor like sass and stylus. However your first option could be more modular and makes your css modules more independent and reusable in other sites, you can then make use of a css minifier to group every declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Organizing your css is really up to you and the number of elements you have.

If you are looking for optimization you should instead focus on useless whitespaces and duplicates.

Tools exist to merge the duplicates and minimize your code ([here](http://devilo.us/) and [here](http://cleancss.com/) for example)

You may also read this [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/18/7-principles-of-clean-and-optimized-css-code/) which is a bit old but still valuable I think.